Drawing hundreds of real-time signal waveforms simultaneously in Qt/C++
I'm developing an oscilloscope project using C++ and Qt that functions more like a logic analyzer, requiring real-time waveform display from hundreds of probes simultaneously.

Each independent hardware probe supports a sampling rate of up to 50Msps. For real-time waveform display (high signal detail isn't necessary), I tried using QCustomPlot, but it fails to handle displaying hundreds of signals concurrently.
What would be the recommended approach to efficiently render and display this many signal waveforms simultaneously? Are there any examples or references I could look into? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

humans cannot see 50 Msps, if a human is seeing this you will barely be refreshing the screen 2-5 times every second

100s of simultaneous plots? For what purpose? In any case, you could have a look at qwt plot. I wrote a plotter before that can plot at least a dozen plots simultaneously (more don't even fit the screen).
